# Clarifying the definition of Boundedness in Uniform Spaces

Tags: general-topology, definition, uniform-spaces

[This excerpt](https://akademiai.com/na101/home/literatum/publisher/kiado/journals/content/10473/1991/10473.1991.57.issue-3-4/bf01903672/production/bf01903672.fp.png_v03) from a journal paper says if X is a uniform space and $A$ is a subset of $X$, then $A$ is said to be bounded if for each entourage $V$, "there exists a finite set $F$ and a positive integer $m$ such that $A\subseteq V^m[F]$".  My question is, what does $V^m[F]$ mean?

The $V^m$ part is clear enough; you just compose $V$ with itself $m$ times.  But I haven't encountered a set in brackets after an entourage.  If it said $V^m[x]$ where $x\in X$, that would make complete sense.  How are the two notations related?  If $F=\{x_1,...,x_n\}$, then does $V^m[F]=\cup_{i=1}^n V^m[x_i]$ or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $R$ is a relation on $X$ (so $R \subseteq X \times X$) then $R[F]$ is just the "functional image" for a subset $F$ of $X$:

$$R[F]=\{y \in X: \exists x \in F: (x,y) \in R\}$$

So yes, this does commute with unions as you suggested.
This is the same definition in essence as $f[F]$ for a function $f: X \to Y$ and $F \subseteq X$; note that a function is just a special case of a relation.

Comment: OK thanks.  Also, why is it necessary to talk about finite sets in the definition rather than just a single point? The definitions of boundedness for metric spaces and topological vector spaces are about sets centered at a single point, so why are things different in the case of uniform spaces?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan One thing is to make clear the relation to compactness, I think. And for a finite space in the trivial uniformity we really need the finite set definition! One point won't do.